# Can't figure out how to use UINavigationControllerDelegate and pushViewController together in a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, delegates, pushviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that conforms to several delegates - shown below:

```
@interface SpotController : UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MKMapViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

For some reason the `NavigationControllerDelegate` portion is not working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Basically I'm trying to push to a new `ViewController` when the tableView's row is selected. I have the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView_ indexPathForSelectedRow];

    // do some stuff here to prep/set stuff on the destination VC

    DetailsVC *detailsVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailsVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsVC animated:YES];
}
```

So, like I said, the `pushViewController` does not work, meaning I do not get sent to the destination VC. I just go no where.

Note: This exact code worked perfectly if I embed the ViewController in a `NavigationController` (I.E. Select the VC in the StoryBoard, then Editor | Embed In | Navigation Controller). **but I don't want to do it this way**.

I've also tried creating an `@property` of type `UINavigationController`, and then alloc-init it in the viewDidLoad. I tried both the `init` and the `initWithRootViewController:self` versions of that method but neither worked. Not sure if I'm even doing that right.

Perhaps I need to specify the `@property` as a delegate explicitly? Not sure how to do that, I've tried doing the following:

```
@synthesize navController = navController_;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] init]; // initWithRootViewController:self];
    [navController_ setDelegate:self];
}
```

But still nothing.

PS - I'm using Xcode 4.3 w/ ARC & Storyboard.

Comment: If you are using the storyboard why don't you create a push segue in the storyboard and then use [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self]? The navigation controller stuff should be controlled automatically for you.

Comment: That would be too easy :) Actually I reall can't do that because of multiple reasons. A) some of the areas of the screen are created programmatically so there is no object on the storyboard to connect up to. B) there are area in the Class that are formed with if statements and depending on certain criteria, push to either one VC or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ask a navigation controller to push new view controllers if it isn't on the screen.

> Note: This exact code worked perfectly if I embed the ViewController in a NavigationController (I.E. Select the VC in the StoryBoard, then Editor | Embed In | Navigation Controller). **but I don't want to do it this way**.

This way, your navigation controller exists and is on the screen. Why don't you want to do it this way?

> I've also tried creating an @property of type UINavigationController, and then alloc-init it in the viewDidLoad. I tried both the init and the initWithRootViewController:self versions of that method but neither worked. Not sure if I'm even doing that right.

This won't work as the navigation controller isn't controlling what is on the screen, it is just existing in memory.

In short, you can't push view controllers onto and off a navigation stack unless *you have an active navigation stack*, and without embedding your VC in a navigation controller, you don't have one. Reconsider your design. You have to embed your VC in a navigation controller if you want to use the features of a navigation controller.

Comment: Oh, his answer's better than mine.  He's right, you can't push a nav controller if it's not on the 'screen'.  Although, technically that just means you can't push if it's not in a view hierarchy that's part of a window.  But that view hierarchy could be 'off-screen' in the sense that the frame is outside of the current viewport.  Then animate it in.  I've done something like this with my own version of a SplitViewController for the iPhone.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! I'll just embed the VC in a Nav Controller and call it a day. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

- One, set a breakpoint and step through your code to make sure that `detailsVC` is correctly being instantiated.  If `detailsVC` isn't being instantiated, you might try alloc/init'ing the `detailsVC` rather than using storyboard (BTW - I've never used storyboard so I don't know the ramifications of that).
- Two, check and make sure that `self.navigationController` is actually returning an object. Again, you would set a breakpoint and in the debug console type `po [self navigationController]` and see what it returns.  If nil is returned then, for some reason, your viewController doesn't have it's navigationController property set, which may have to do with the view controller hierarchy you have set up.  You can try to fix that, or manually pass and keep a reference to the navigation controller in your view controller.